# compass/css fade border at edges?

Tags: css, compass-sass

I've seen this technique used quite a lot. Like say a separator border (like bottom border for stackoverflow header) which fades at both ends. How do I achieve this with compass? I've searched their documentation and google and can't find any examples of how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used Compass CSS, but how about mixing CSS and SVG?

**Your SVG file:**

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="div" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255, 255, 225);stop-opacity:0"/>
            <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgb(153,153,153);stop-opacity:1"/>
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255, 255, 225);stop-opacity:0"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>

<rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#div)" />
</svg>
```

**The CSS:**

```
div.separator
{
    width: 80%;
    height: 16px;
    background-image: url(gradient_file.svg);
}
```

Comment: Do you think this might be easier with javascript? Thanks for the SVG suggestion! I'll try that too.

Comment: @Zenph I think it would be more tricky with JavaScript. And no problem, let me know how you get on!